# How to keep consistent colors (set by theme) in R markdown document across multiple ggplot2 plots for discreet variable with changing set of levels

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, quarto

I'm trying to understand theming in Quarto html documents. First I set up theme in YAML. Then setup thematic  by running `thematic::thematic_rmd()`. But when i filter out one of the levels of factor, and use `scale_color_discrete(limits=levels(mtcars$cyl))` to keep colors consistent, it breaks the theme colors. What am i doing wrong?
Also, the plots do not follow the theme from YAML

The example Rmd document looks like this:

````
---
title: "Consistent colours"
format:
  html:
    theme: darkly
---

## Example

```{r}
#| label: setup

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

thematic::thematic_rmd()

data(mtcars, package="datasets")
mtcars$cyl = as.factor(mtcars$cyl)
```

Plot with all the factor levels:

```{r}
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=hp, y=mpg, color=cyl)) + geom_point(size=5)
```

Plot wit one less factor level:

```{r}
ggplot(filter(mtcars, cyl != "6"), aes(x=hp, y=mpg, color=cyl)) + geom_point(size=5) + scale_color_discrete(limits=levels(mtcars$cyl), drop=TRUE)
```
````